# The man near the door who is pretending to be cool who has a red hat is a friend of Jane

Tags: relative-clauses, commas, noun-phrases, lists

My original sentence is

> The man near the door who is pretending to be cool who has a red hat is a friend of Jane.

In this sentence, I intended to use "*defining relative clause*" with "*who*" and give the meaning:

> The man near the door is a friend of Jane. He is who is pretending to be cool and has a red hat.

Is my original sentence correct or must I use commas even if "*who relative clauses*" are defining relative clauses like:

> The man near the door, who is pretending to be cool, and who has a red hat is a friend of Jane.

I don't think the last one is correct because it seems that there is a list whose first element is "near the door", which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The original is particularly "clumsy" without the conjunction ***and*** before the second "who-" clause. Other than that, imho it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to use any commas at all in the written version. If you *do* want to include commas I'd say you need at least two (one before and one after the entire "parenthetical" element *who is pretending to be cool and who has a red hat*), but you could break that text up with another comma before ***and***. Note that the sentence is always going to be *somewhat* clumsy with those two "who-" clauses (but it can serve as an example).

Comment: (Note that your *final* version is definitely orthographically invalid. If you're going to have commas delineating the *first* "who-" clause, you need to do the same with the second one for consistency. So there *must* be another comma after ***hat***. But I don't think the concept of "list" is relevant or helpful here.)

Comment: But at least, I believe that I can assume the relative clause "who is pretending to be cool" refers to the phrase "the man near the door" and "who  has a red hat" refers to the phrase "the man near the door who is pretending to be cool". I think this structure is grammatical.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking (*without* conjunction ***and*** mentioned above), I'd say it's quite true that *"who has a red hat" refers to the phrase "the man near the door who is pretending to be cool"*. But in practice I think no native speaker would normally write or say exactly that. They *would* include the conjunction, in which case *"who has a red hat" refers to the phrase "the man near the door"*. Also in practice that's just "syntactic breakdown" for the sake of it - no-one would understand the *meaning* to be any different between those two alternatives.

Comment: ...and native speakers wouldn't normally "stack up" multiple "who-" clauses like that anyway. We'd more likely say something like *The man near the door with a red hat who's pretending to be cool is a friend of Jane's.* Probably with no particular pauses or commas.